# Am I missing unity multiplayer packages or trying to use depreciated ones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an online 2D turn based game in unity 2021.3.18f1 using unity Netcode for Game Objects. I've run into a fairly major issue as follows:
Using `[SyncVar]`, returns the error `The type or namespace name 'SyncVarAttribute' could not be found` despite having the correct using tags.
 I've tried referencing the namespace dirrectly by changing it to `[UnityEngine.Networking.SyncVar]`, this returns the very similar error `The type or namespace name 'SyncVarAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Networking'`.
For reference I have Netcode and multiplayer tools installed and am using [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/Manual/class-NetworkBehaviour.html) as my guide.

Not sure if this code is too helpfull but here's the relevant parts of the `GameController` script:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class GameController : NetworkBehaviour
{
//throws the first error
[SyncVar] private int currentPlayer = 0;
//throws the second error
[UnityEngine.Networking.SyncVar] private List<PlayerController> players = new List<PlayerController>();
}
```

I'm aware I might not be able to use `[SyncVar]` on the `players` variable as it is not a basic class but I'll deal with that when if/when i get to it. here are a few screenshots as well in case that helps:
[Network Manager Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVB9h.png)
[Package Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMEr2.png)
[Network Object on GameController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6BLj.png)

Hope this is enough information, thanks in advance for the advice

Comment: Do you really not have a using UnityEngine at the top of that code?

Comment: Sorry it does also have using UnityEngine It just had so many ones I removed to put it on here. I must have lost it with the other randoms

Answer (score 0):

For others finding this use

```
NetworkVariable<T>
```

Eg

Change

```
[SyncVar]
public int health;
```

to

```
public NetworkVariable<int> health;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).